# Excel 2016 - Removing duplicate rows from Column A while merging numbers from column B

Tags: excel, spreadsheet

I have a load of data concerning website page views and some time ago we changed the way the url's are displayed (column A) within the data. So now I have to remove the duplicated url's as well as merge the page views (column B and C) but the data showed both www.mywebsite.com and mywebsite.com.

I have managed to change the url's so they are all the same format (www.mywebsite.com/......) though I am see a lot of duplicates (Expected). Is there are way to tell excel to merge the data from columns B & C where it finds duplicate url's in Column A?

After I have done this then I will paste the results so nothing will change after deleting the duplicates.

Comment: Can you include a screenshot of your data? I think I'm picturing it correctly, but I want to make sure. You can upload it to imgur.com and post the link if you don't have enough reputation to post it here.

Comment: Merge?? how do you want to do that? add them? concatenate them? or overwrite?